# Run through all classes and extract information with maven

Tags: java, maven, plugins

I want to write a Maven plugin, that runs through all the sources and extracts classes that are annotated with a special annotation, to write them into an HTML file.

Is this possible? If yes, is there any recommended way?

Comment: Can you please mention what you would like to be extracted from the sources? Is it similar to JavaDoc creation?

Comment: Would JavaDoc not be a better candidate as Maven can already generate JavaDoc.  Is the annotation part of the class like say `@Entity`, if it is only for documentation purposes I would look into extending JavaDoc.

Comment: Yes pretty similar. It should watch for a specific annotation and create a directory of the classes that are annotated with it. @KavithaKarunakaran

Comment: Of course there is also the likes of Swagger, but your milage might vary there.

Comment: @Gavin Yes I already have JavaDoc. But basically I want to create a directory of important Classes for a project. It is only documentation, but it should only document specific Classes (those that are interesting for other people in a project)

Comment: @Gavin What do you mean with Swagger? I have only used it with C# to auto generate API documentation yet.

Comment: @MauriceNino - I think you can reuse maven-resources-plugin for this.

Comment: In theory I believe you can extend JavaDoc, so this would be the route I would initially look at as it is designed to document things and maven already has a plugin for it.  As to Swagger, it can be used to generate docs for Java as well, when I used it, you could generate quite sophisticated documentation, though I think there was a lot of YAML involved, i think you annotated the classes as well though.

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran Isn't it only for copying files? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Gavin So you mean I should look if the `maven-javadoc-plugin` has a function for something like this? Because I kind of hate that plugin.

Comment: I think one issue with copy the classes to a directory for interested parties is that you are exposing the internals of the class, you are basically making it public, and rightly or wrongly clients might start to depend on the inner works continuing to work that way.

Comment: @MauriceNino not something I have done, but I think its the actual JavaDoc processor you have to extend, not the plugin

Comment: @MauriceNino - sorry. I meant maven-javadoc-plugin.

Comment: That seems like something I can't really do with confidence. I would really like to implement it with Java Code, because I am not really familiar with Maven/The JavaDoc processor. @Gavin

Comment: @Gavin - good suggestion

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran Ok thanks for the suggestion. To be honest, it took me some time to get the output to look the way I want it to look with the Maven plugin, so I have seen a lot of settings of this plugin. I can't think of any, that would help me with that problem. Do you know any?

Comment: @MauriceNino - I understand your frustration. But at the moment, if you have grouped your important classes under specific packages  you can use <excludePackageNames> to specify multiple paths that need not be documented. I hope you find that useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the asm library. It is pretty powerful in scanning bytecode. You can go through the `.class` files and scan them for annotations.

It is, though, non-trivial because you need to understand the details of the visitor pattern that is applied.